# hasOwnProperty in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Consider:

```
function Shape() {
    this.name = "Generic";
    this.draw = function() {
        return "Drawing " + this.name + " Shape";
    };
}

function welcomeMessage()
{
    var shape1 = new Shape();
    //alert(shape1.draw());
    alert(shape1.hasOwnProperty(name));  // This is returning false
}
```

`.welcomeMessage` called on the `body.onload` event.

I expected `shape1.hasOwnProperty(name)` to return true, but it's returning false.

What is the correct behavior?

Comment: it requires a string, so `"name"` as opposed to `name`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript what is property in hasOwnProperty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396569/javascript-what-is-property-in-hasownproperty)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

`hasOwnProperty` is a normal JavaScript function that takes a string argument.

When you call `shape1.hasOwnProperty(name)` you are passing it the value of the `name` variable (which doesn't exist), just as it would if you wrote `alert(name)`.

You need to call `hasOwnProperty` with a string containing `name`, like this: `shape1.hasOwnProperty("name")`.

Comment: Don't forget to add the hasOwnProperty() returns a boolean value indicating the property (in this case name) specified exists or not

Answer (score 19):

`hasOwnProperty` expects the property name as a string, so it would be `shape1.hasOwnProperty("name")`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function welcomeMessage()
{
    var shape1 = new Shape();
    //alert(shape1.draw());
    alert(shape1.hasOwnProperty("name"));
}
```

When working with reflection in JavaScript, member objects are always refered to as the name as a string. For example:

`for(i in obj) { ... }`

The loop iterator i will be hold a string value with the name of the property. To use that in code you have to address the property using the array operator like this:

```
 for(i in obj) {
   alert("The value of obj." + i + " = " + obj[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

**hasOwnProperty()** is a nice property to validate object keys.
**Example:**

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2};

obj.hasOwnProperty('a') // true
```

Comment: Re *"nice property"*: Isn't it a function?