# What is property in hasOwnProperty in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, hasownproperty, es2022

Consider:

```
if (someVar.hasOwnProperty('someProperty') ) {
 // Do something();
} else {
 // Do somethingElse();
}
```

What is the right use/explanation of `hasOwnProperty('someProperty')`?

Why can't we simply use `someVar.someProperty` to check if an object `someVar` contains property with name `someProperty`?

What is a property in this case?

What property does this JavaScript check?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600085/hasownproperty-in-javascript

Comment: When I asked this question I thought it was a function that checked some html. Now I see it checking a javascript object or method for a 'variable' within that object or method. thnx!

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty

Answer (score 208, accepted):

`hasOwnProperty` returns a boolean value indicating whether the object on which you are calling it has a property with the name of the argument. For example:

```
var x = {
    y: 10
};
console.log(x.hasOwnProperty("y")); //true
console.log(x.hasOwnProperty("z")); //false
```

However, it does not look at the prototype chain of the object.

It's useful to use it when you enumerate the properties of an object with the `for...in` construct.

If you want to see the full details, the [ES5 specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.5) is, as always, a good place to look.

Comment: Bonus points for prototype chain. Still trying to figure out what its calling on when its not called on an object... its not `window`

Comment: @KristofferSHansen - I was wondering that too, but the question has been edited so it's now being called on an object. When it's not, an error is thrown.

Comment: I suppose that changes things. No error when run from console in Chrome though.

Comment: @KristofferSHansen - I think that's because of how the console runs code (it's run as `eval` code rather than global or function code). I tried it in a blank HTML page and get a "cannot convert null to object" error.

Comment: @KristofferSHansen see Kunal Vashist answer when it is called on a class method

Comment: @scubaFLY my comment was based on the original question where it wasn't used as a class method.

Answer (score 48):

Here is a short and precise answer:

In JavaScript, every object has a bunch of built-in key-value pairs that have meta information about the object. When you loop through all the key-value pairs using `for...in` construct/loop for an object you're looping through this meta-information key-value pairs too (which you definitely don't want).

[image]

Using `hasOwnPropery(property)` **filters-out** these unnecessary looping through meta information and directly checks that is the parameter `property` is a user-given property in the object or not.
By **filters-out**, I mean, that `hasOwnProperty(property)` does not look if, `property` exists in Object's prototype chain aka meta information.

It returns boolean `true/false` based on that.

Here is an example:

```js
var fruitObject = {"name": "Apple", "shape": "round", "taste": "sweet"};
console.log(fruitObject.hasOwnProperty("name"));  //true
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("toString")) // true because in above snapshot you can see, that there is a function toString in meta-information
```

I hope it's clear!

Comment: at last line of your example you write `console.log(Object.prototype....`; did you mean `console.log(fruitObject.`? fruitObject or Object ?

Comment: >"you're looping through this meta-information key-value pairs too"
But when I run `for (var key in fruitObject) { ... }` js only cycle's through non-prototype keys anyway, am I missing something or did JS runtime change the way they handle for key-in-object loops?

Answer (score 16):

It checks:

Returns a Boolean value indicating whether an object has a property with the specified name

The [hasOwnProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/328kyd6z%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) method returns true if the object has a property of the specified name, false if it does not. This method does not check if the property exists in the object's prototype chain; the property must be a member of the object itself.

**Example:**

```
var s = new String("Sample");
document.write(s.hasOwnProperty("split"));                        //false
document.write(String.prototype.hasOwnProperty("split"));         //true
```

Comment: I gave a -1 because your initial answer was a short and utterly incoherent sentence, which was then updated to a slightly longer, slightly more coherent, but entirely inaccurate sentence.

Comment: @amnotiam- but i think its much clear now...its because my internet issue i cannot able to post more..........

Answer (score 16):

### Summary:

`hasOwnProperty()` is a function which can be called on any object and takes a string as an input. It returns a boolean which is `true` if the property is located on the object, otherwise it returns false. `hasOwnProperty()` is located on `Object.prototype` and thus available for any object.

### Example:

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.age = 25;

const willem = new Person('willem');

console.log(willem.name); // Property found on object
console.log(willem.age); // Property found on prototype

console.log(willem.hasOwnProperty('name')); // 'name' is on the object itself
console.log(willem.hasOwnProperty('age')); // 'age' is not on the object itself
```

In this example a new Person object is created. Each Person has its own name which gets initialized in the constructor. However, the age is not located on the object but on the prototype of the object. Therefore `hasOwnProperty()` does return `true` for name and `false` for age.

### Practical applications:

`hasOwnProperty()` can be very useful when looping over an object using a `for in` loop. You can check with it if the properties are from the object itself and not the prototype. For example:

```js
function Person(name, city) {
  this.name = name;
  this.city = city;
}

Person.prototype.age = 25;

const willem = new Person('Willem', 'Groningen');

for (let trait in willem) {
  console.log(trait, willem[trait]); // This loops through all properties, including the prototype
}

console.log('\n');

for (let trait in willem) {
  if (willem.hasOwnProperty(trait)) { // This loops only through 'own' properties of the object
    console.log(trait, willem[trait]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You use object.hasOwnProperty(**p**) to determine if an object has an **enumerable** property **p**-

An object can have its own prototype, where 'default' methods and attributes are assigned to every instance of the object. hasOwnProperty returns true only for the properties that were specifically set in the constructor, or added to the instance later.

To determine if **p** is defined at all, anywhere, for the object, use if(**p** instanceof object), where p evaluates to a property-name string.

For example, by default all objects have a 'toString' method, but it will not show up in hasOwnProperty.

Answer (score 4):

`hasOwnProperty` is a proper way of checking an *object* has a *property* or not. `someVar.someProperty` cannot be used as an alternative to this situation. The following condition will show a good difference:

```
const someVar = { isFirst: false };


// The condition is true, because 'someVar' has property 'isFirst'
if (someVar.hasOwnProperty('isFirst')) {
  // Code runs
}


// The condition is false, because 'isFirst' is false.
if (someVar.isFirst) {
  // Code does not runs here
}
```

Hence `someVar.isFirst` cannot be used alternative to `someVar.hasOwnProperty('isFirst')`.

Answer (score 2):

hasOwnProperty is a normal JavaScript function that takes a string argument.

In your case, `somevar.hasOwnProperty('someProperty')`, it checks the `somevar` function has `somepropery` or not - it returns true and false.

Say

```
function somevar() {
    this.someProperty = "Generic";
}

function welcomeMessage()
{
    var somevar1 = new somevar();
    if(somevar1.hasOwnProperty("name"))
    {
        alert(somevar1.hasOwnProperty("name")); // It will return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**2021 - Object.hasOwn as a replacement for Object.hasOwnProperty()**

As other answers indicated, `hasOwnProperty` will check for an object own properties in contrast to `in` which will also check for inherited properties.

There is a new alternative method called `Object.hasOwn()` and is intended to be a replacement for `Object.hasOwnProperty()`

`Object.hasOwn()` is a static method which returns true if the specified object has the specified property as its own property. If the property is inherited, or does not exist, the method returns false.

```js
const person = { name: 'dan' };

console.log(Object.hasOwn(person, 'name'));// true
console.log(Object.hasOwn(person, 'age'));// false

const person2 = Object.create({gender: 'male'});

console.log(Object.hasOwn(person2, 'gender'));// false
```

It is recommended to this method use over the `Object.hasOwnProperty()` because it also works for objects created by using `Object.create(null)` and for objects that have overridden the inherited `hasOwnProperty()` method. Although it's possible to solve these kind of problems by calling `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()` on an external object, `Object.hasOwn()`  overcome these problems, hence is preferred (see examples below)

```js
let person = {
  hasOwnProperty: function() {
    return false;
  },
  age: 35
};

if (Object.hasOwn(person, 'age')) {
  console.log(person.age); // true - the remplementation of hasOwnProperty() did not affect the Object
}
```

```js
let person = Object.create(null);
person.age = 35;
if (Object.hasOwn(person, 'age')) {
  console.log(person.age); // true - works regardless of how the object was created
}
```

More about `Object.hasOwn` can be found here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn

Browser compatibility - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

*What is the right use/explanation of hasOwnProperty('someProperty') ?*

The `hasOwnProperty()` method returns a `boolean` indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it).

```js
const someVar = {};
someVar.someProperty = 'Foo';

console.log(someVar.hasOwnProperty('someProperty'));
// expected output: true

console.log(someVar.hasOwnProperty('someProperty1'));
// expected output: false
```

*Why can't we simply use someVar.someProperty to check if an object someVar contains property with name someProperty ?*

`someVar.someProperty` will return the property value, You can not check that this property is available in the object or not via `someVar.someProperty`.

Now in ES2022, A new method has been introduced which is `Object.hasOwn(<object reference>, <property name>)` this method is intended as a replacement for `Object.hasOwnProperty()` which overcome some limitations of `.hasOwnProperty()`.

Answer (score 0):

## Scene A:

```
const objA = { a: 1, b: 2 }
for (const key in objA) {
  if (objA.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(objA[key])
  }
}

    Output

    1
    2
```

## Scene B:

```
const objB = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  hasOwnProperty() {
    return false
  }
}

for (const key in objB) {
  if (objB.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(objB[key])
  }
}

    Outputs nothing
```

**Because JavaScript doesn't protect the property of hasOwnProperty.**
**So you can use it like this:**

```
for (const key in objB) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
    console.log(objB[key])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case someVar is Object. Object has a prototype calls 'hasOwnProperty'. Property means a value for key in Object.

For example:

```
const objectTest = {key1: property1, key2: property2}
If (objectTest.hasOwnProperty('key1')) {
return true
}
else { return false }
```

In this case we got true, because key1 has property1.

If you want to check more information for this prototype, you can read [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Answer (score -2):

It [checks if an object has a property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty). It works the same as `if(obj.prop)`, as far as I know.

Comment: `obj.prop` follows the prototype chain, `hasOwnProperty` does not

Comment: The problem is when `prop` has false value. `if(obj.hasOwnProperty('prop'))` will be `true` while `if(obj.prop)` will be `false`.