# how to get keys from object list in json string in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
[null, {
  "display_with": "7",
  "id": "1",
  "image": "/images/salt_sugar.png",
  "name": "Salt and Sugar",
  "subcategories": {
    "1": true,
    "6": true,
    "7": true
  }
}, {
  "display_with": "6",
  "id": "2",
  "image": "/images/tea_and_coffee.png",
  "name": "Tea and Coffee",
  "subcategories": {
    "8": true,
    "9": true,
    "124": true
  }
}]
```

In the above string i want 1, 6, 7 and 8, 9, 124 from second and third record respectively.

This is my logic.

recvCategories = JSON STRING

```
for (var j=0; j<recvCategories.length; ++j){
    var category =  recvCategories[j];

    if (category != undefined){
        var subcategories = [];
        int size = Object.keys(category.subcategories).length;

        for (var property in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to print 1, 6, 7 and 8, 9, 124 in // do stuff ??

Comment: [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: You can do `subcategories.push()` and later you can print it. Also note, `object.keys` should be sufficient. And `Object.keys(category.subcategories).length;` this can break your code if object does not has property subcategories

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting JavaScript object key list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068534/getting-javascript-object-key-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is named `data` this should do it.

```
var keys = [];
data.forEach(d => {
    if (d.subcategories)
        for (var key in d.subcategories)
            keys.push(key);
})
```

It may look simple however by using a `for(var x in y)` will actually iterate the properties of an object and return the propertyNames.

So in the example we call the `.forEach()` method in an array and then iterate each key of subcategories `push`ing them into a new array.

Answer (score 1):

Something like,

```
for( i in aList) { 
    console.log(keys(aList[i] && aList[i].subcategories)) 
}
// []
// [1, 6, 7]
// [8, 9, 124]
```

Answer (score 0):

Few pointers in your code:

- This condition: `if (category != undefined)` will not validate `null` and code will throw on `object.something`
- `Object.keys(category.subcategories).length;` will break if you do not have property `subcategories` in object. You can try something like this `(Object.keys(category.subcategories) || []).length`
- Also if you create your own custom object, then it makes sense to use `object.hasOwnProperty`, but if you are reading form JSON, you can rely on `Object.keys`

You can also try something like this:

```js
function getSubCategoriesKeys(d){
  return d.reduce(function(p,c){
    if(!isEmpty(c) && typeof(c) === "object" && c.hasOwnProperty("subcategories")){
      p = p.concat(Object.keys(c.subcategories))
    }
    return p;
  }, [])
}

function isEmpty(o){
  return o === undefined || o === null || o.toString().trim().length === 0
}

var data = [null, {
  "display_with": "7",
  "id": "1",
  "image": "/images/salt_sugar.png",
  "name": "Salt and Sugar",
  "subcategories": {
    "1": true,
    "6": true,
    "7": true
  }
}, {
  "display_with": "6",
  "id": "2",
  "image": "/images/tea_and_coffee.png",
  "name": "Tea and Coffee",
  "subcategories": {
    "8": true,
    "9": true,
    "124": true
  }
}]

var keys = getSubCategoriesKeys(data);
console.log(keys)
```

#### Reference

- [what is property in hasownproperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396569/javascript-what-is-property-in-hasownproperty)