# Is there a benefit to use "hasOwnProperty()" when iterating through object keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand the goal of using `hasOwnProperty()` check when iterating through object keys. As I know, the iteration will be executed for every object property (not more, not less) in both cases: with `hasOwnProperty()` or without. For example, in code below results with `hasOwnProperty()` check and without are the same:

```js
const obj = {
  prop1: [],
  prop2: {},
  prop3: "",
  prop4: 0,
  prop5: null,
  prop6: undefined
}

const resultWithHasOwnProperty = [];
const resultWithoutHasOwnProperty = [];

for(key in obj) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    resultWithHasOwnProperty.push(obj[key])
  }
}

for(key in obj) {
  resultWithoutHasOwnProperty.push(obj[key])
}

console.log("Result WITH hasOwnProperty check: ", resultWithHasOwnProperty);
console.log("Result WITHOUT hasOwnProperty check: ", resultWithoutHasOwnProperty);
```

So my question is: why and when should we use `hasOwnProperty()` check?

I'll rephrase my question: without `hasOwnProperty()` check we will always iterate through all existing properties anyway?

*Notice, this question is not really a duplicate.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript what is property in hasOwnProperty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396569/javascript-what-is-property-in-hasownproperty)

Comment: I'll rephrase my question: without `hasOwnProperty()` check we will always iterate through all existing properties anyway?

Comment: Good article here: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/the-uses-of-in-vs-hasownproperty.html

Comment: @jmargolisvt, thanks for the link ;)

Comment: See [Can I finally let `hasOwnProperty()` die in for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45014347/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi, Oh, cool, thanks for that link, interesting post

Comment: you _almost never_ need to use `.hasOwnProperty()`.    jQuery manages perfectly well (and intentionally so) without it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The docs indicate that:

> The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the
>   object has the specified property as own (not inherited) property.

The `hasOwnProperty` method ensure that the property you are checking is directly on an instance of an object but not inherited from its prototype chain. If you don't check, it will loop through every property on the prototype chain.

```
const obj = {
  prop1: [],
  prop2: {},
  prop3: "",
  prop4: 0,
  prop5: null,
  prop6: undefined
}

obj.prototype = {foo: 'bar'};
```

---

P/s: **NOTE** that:

JavaScript does not protect the property name `hasOwnProperty`; thus, if the possibility exists that an object might have a property with this name, it is necessary to use an external `hasOwnProperty` to get correct results:

```
var foo = {
  hasOwnProperty: function() {
    return false;
  },
  bar: 'Here be dragons'
};

foo.hasOwnProperty('bar'); // always returns false
```

So you need to use:

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, 'bar');
```

Comment: Cool, short and clear! I'll accept your answer after timeout

Comment: I added a note for `hasOwnProperty` as well :)