# JS map object names recursively

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recursion

I have an array of objects, with undefined depth.
Now I want the names to be output as follows:

```
Top Level
Top Level > Sub 1
Top Level > Sub 1 > Sub 1-2
Top Level > Sub 2
```

However, I always get only the lowest element. I don't know what else I could change to get the names formatted correctly.

```
        parseCategories(categories, stackCounter = 0) {
          categories.forEach(c => {
            this.res[stackCounter] = { name: c.attributes.name, id: c.id };
            if(c.children.length >= 1) {
              this.parseCategories(c.children, stackCounter + 1);
            }
          });
          return this.res;
        }
```

My Objects looks like this:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "type":"categories",
         "id":"1",
         "attributes":{
            "name":"Top Level"
         },
         "children":[
            {
               "type":"categories",
               "id":"2",
               "attributes":{
                  "name":"Sub 1"
               },
               "children":[
                  {
                     "type":"categories",
                     "id":"4",
                     "attributes":{
                        "name":"Sub 1-2"
                     },
                     "children":[

                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "type":"categories",
               "id":"3",
               "attributes":{
                  "name":"Sub 2"
               },
               "children":[

               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396569/javascript-what-is-property-in-hasownproperty, and this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys. Also javascript has a Map() function and a flatMap() function that could help you.

Comment: I dont need to check if the props are available, I know they are, I search a solution to concatenate the upper categorie names with the child names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often generator functions will simplify such traversals.  Here we can write a quite simple generator then wrap it in a function that creates an array from that generator:

```js
const getPaths = function * (xs, ps = []) {
  for (let x of xs) {
    yield [... ps, x .attributes .name] .join (' > ')
    yield * getPaths (x .children, [...ps, x .attributes .name])
  }
}

const categoryNames = (categories) => 
  [... getPaths (categories .data)]

const categories = {data: [{type: "categories", id: "1", attributes: {name: "Top Level"}, children: [{type: "categories", id: "2", attributes: {name: "Sub 1"}, children: [{type: "categories", id: "4", attributes: {name: "Sub 1-2"}, children: []}]}, {type: "categories", id: "3", attributes: {name: "Sub 2"}, children: []}]}]};

console .log (
  categoryNames(categories)
)
```

`getPaths` might be made a little more generic by removing the `join (' > ')` call and adding it inside a `map` call at the end of `categoryNames`.  But since the `children` and `attributes.names` is already fairly problem-specific, I probably wouldn't bother.

---

### Explanation

You said you didn't entirely follow this code.  This is an attempt to explain it.  Please don't be offended if I explain something you already understand.  It's not clear to me exactly what needs to be explained.

The outer function, `categoryNames` is a very small wrapper around `getPaths`.  That one does all the work.

There are two important features to note about `getPaths`:

- It is a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), noted by the `*` between the `function` keyword and the list of arguments.  Generator functions create [Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) objects, which, because they conform to the [iterable protocol], can be used inside such constructs as `let x of generator` and `[...generator]`.  That is how `categoryNames` converts the output of `getPaths` into an array.  (Incidentally, the iterable protocol is also how the `for-of` loop in `getPaths` converts an array into a sequence of values.)  Generator functions work by `yield`ing individual values or using `yield * anotherGenerator` to individually produce each of the values yielded by another generator.  In between these `yield` calls the function is suspended until the next value is requested.
- It is a [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion); the body of the function invokes that same function again, with simpler parameters.  Most often in recursive functions you will see an explicit base case, where the answer is returned directly without a recursive call when the input is simple enough.  Here that base case is implicit.  When `xs` is an empty array, the body of the `for-loop` is never invoked, so the recursion ends.

`getPaths` accepts an array of values (`xs` is my default name for a list of values of an unknown type; `nodes` would also be a good name) and it accepts an array of strings representing the paths in the hierarchy up to the current node.  So it might for instance contain `["Top Level", "Sub 1"]`.  Note that this is a [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters); if you don't supply it, it will be given an empty array.

We loop over the values supplied to us.  For each one, we first yield the result of combining the current paths and the the `name` property of the `attribute` property of our current object by interspersing `" > "` between them.  Then we recur by passing the child and an array of names including the current one, yielding each of its children in turn.  This version might be both slightly more performant and a bit easier to read:

```js
const getPaths = function * (xs, paths = []) {
  for (let x of xs) {
    const newPaths = [... paths, x .attributes .name]
    yield newPaths .join (' > ')
    yield * getPaths (x .children, newPaths)
  }
}
```

And if you wanted, you could define `newPaths` like this instead:

```
    const newPaths = paths .concat (node .attributes .name)
```

I hope that helps.  If you have questions about this, please add a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I just read myself into "traverse tree" and will probably have to develop some examples.
I don't quite understand your code, but I'll get used to it now.

Comment: @Phil795: Added an explanation.  Hope it's a bit more understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this block

```
categories.forEach(c => {
  this.res[stackCounter] = { name: c.attributes.name, id: c.id };
});
```

You can see that `res[stackCounter]` is always overridden by last element of `categories`. To fix this, `res[stackCounter]` should be an array also.

```
parseCategories(categories, stackCounter = 0) {
  // init res[stackCounter]
  if (this.res[stackCounter]) {
    this.res[stackCounter] = [];
  }
  categories.forEach(c => {
    this.res[stackCounter].push({ name: c.attributes.name, id: c.id }); // push to res[stackCounter]
    if(c.children.length >= 1) {
      this.parseCategories(c.children, stackCounter + 1);
    }
  });
  return this.res;
}
```

Comment: This produces: ```[[{"name":"Top Level","id":"1"}],[{"name":"Sub 1","id":"2"},{"name":"Sub 2","id":"3"}],[{"name":"Sub 1-2","id":"4"}]]```
And I want to get alle parent category names concatenated

Comment: Your problem is related to Tree Data structure. Specifically, "traverse" the tree. You should look for it and learn it since it's one of the most important and popular data structures