# hasOwnProperty is not returning correct value

Tags: javascript

hasOwnProperty is not returning correct value.

I have two set of data.

```
var data1 = {
  "Name": "Ana",
  "Class": 3,
  "index": 0,
  "Subject": [
    {
      "Sub1": "Maths",
      "Sub2": "Science",
      "index": 00,
      "Speciality": [
        {
          "Spcl": "Music",
          "Spcl2": "Sports",
          "Spcl3": "Singing",
          "index": "000"
        }
      ]
    }]
}

var data2 = {

"Subject": [
    {
      "Sub1": "Maths",
      "Sub2": "Science",
      "index": 00,
      "Speciality": [
        {
          "Spcl": "Music",
          "Spcl2": "Sports",
          "Spcl3": "Singing",
          "index": "000"
        }
      ]
    }

}
```

When I am giving `data1.hasOwnProperty(data2)` it is returning false. What is wrong in this code. data 1 have "subject"

Comment: `data2` is an object, which is not the appropriate parameter for `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` does not do a deep comparison of objects. It merely checks to see if the object has a specified `key`. So `data1.hasOwnProperty('Subject')` would yield `true`

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` does not dig into the object and compare everything.  It just checks if the object has the *key* you are looking for.  `data1` does not have (and cannot have) an object as a key, so it returns `false`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty - remember to refer to references for expected behavior.

Comment: so to access the "subject" do I need to use for loop @zzzzBov

Answer (score 1):

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9396647/129086):

> `hasOwnProperty` returns a boolean value indicating whether the object on which you are calling it has a property with the name of the argument.

`data2` is an object, not a property name.

**What you're trying to do is to compare two object values.** Search for "comparing two objects", and you'll find several great answers on how to approach that task.

Comment: ya I understtod, So in this case what is the javascript way to access the "subject" from data2. Assuming I have only one object in data2,and I don't wann use "subject" in my code

Comment: `Object.values(data2)[0]`