# JS: checking object with key vs hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at the solution below to the "two sum" problem.  They iterated through the array first and put all the numbers in an object.  Then they did another `for` loop to see if the different was a key in the array but they checked for the key using `hasOwnProperty`.  What is the difference of doing that vs. just checking for the key ex:  `if (obj[key]) { ....}`

```
const twoSum_On_Better = (arr, target) => {
    let numObject = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let thisNum = arr[i];
        numObject[thisNum] = i;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let diff = target - arr[i];
        if (numObject.hasOwnProperty(diff) && numObject[diff] !== i) {
            return [i, numObject[diff]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out Om Sao's answer here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396569/what-is-property-in-hasownproperty-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Using `obj[key]` has two potential downsides:

- It will check if the property is *truthy*, not only that the property exists

```js
const obj = {
  prop: 0,
};
console.log(Boolean(obj.prop));
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('prop'));
```

- It will perform the above check on the *first* object in the prototype chain that has the property. In contrast, `hasOwnProperty` will only check if *the object itself*, and not any of its internal prototypes, have the property.

```js
const objProto = {
  prop: 'val',
};
const obj = Object.create(objProto);

console.log(Boolean(obj.prop));
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('prop'));
```

If, like in this case, you aren't dealing with prototypal inheritance, and the values on the object are sure to be truthy if they exist, feel free to use `obj[key]`.

Some suggest to avoid dynamic property names in modern JS and to use [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead for purposes like these.

Comment: thanks for the clear and concise explanation :)

Comment: For what I understood, if value of key is boolean, then using [key], will result to the boolean value, and not the presence of the key. This clear things. Thanks!