# Loop through an object of objects with arrays as values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

So I have an object like this:

```
{
  "apples": [
    "one",
    "two"
  ],
  "oranges": [
    "three",
    "four"
  ]
}
```

How do I look through this object and find `four` for example? Something like:

```
for (var i=0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  for (var y=0; y <obj.childObj.length; y++ {
    obj.childObj[i] === 'four' ? return : null;
  }
}
```

Or is there a better way to structure this data?

Comment: Your code is wrong. `return` cannot be used like that. what is your requirement.

Comment: what exactly do you want to return?

Comment: it depends on the purpose. if you always search for four, then an object with a key four would make sense.

Comment: Don't use same variable in nested loops for iteration in your case `i`;

Comment: Structure as you want (if you are looking for values that are not unique and good enough to be used as hashmap keys), you are going through all the elements one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var x in obj)
 if(obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
  for(var y in obj[x])
   if(obj[x].hasOwnProperty(y)) {
    obj[x][y] === 'four' ? doSomething() : doSomethingElse();
   }
  }
```

EDIT : Improvement as suggested by Matthew Herbst

Comment: Looks good initially. Is this the most efficient way to store and retrieve multi-dimensional information like this though?

Comment: Make sure to also use `obj.hasOwnProperty(x)` and `obj[x].hasOwnProperty(y)`

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way which could give you a significant performance boost over this one.

Comment: What is the benefit of hasOwnProperty?

Comment: @JohnDoe It'll check only for the own properties and not for the inherited properties. See [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) Also see [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600085/hasownproperty-in-javascript)

Comment: The check prevents inherit properties from being iterated over, If there are any. If you have an object that inherits too many properties and you don't want them being iterated over, Object.keys could be a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for (x in y)` statemment:

```
var data = {
  "apples": [
    "one",
    "two"
  ],
  "oranges": [
    "three",
    "four"
  ]
};

for (var key in data) {
    var obj = data[key];
    for (var i=0; i <obj.length; i++) {
        // obj[i] === 'four' ? return : null;
        console.log(obj[i]);
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
one
two
three
four
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out if this object has four somewhere then

```
var isFourAvailable = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(val){ return obj[val].indexOf("four") != -1 }).length > 0;
```

Making it more generic

```
function findX(x)
{
   return Object.keys(obj).filter(function(val){ return obj[val].indexOf(x) != -1 }).length > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

Modified your code;

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < obj[i].length; y++ {
    if(obj[i][y] === 'four'){
      console.log("It's four");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf

```
   var x={
      "apples": [
        "one",
        "two"
      ],
      "oranges": [
        "three",
        "four"
      ]
    }
    for (var e in x) {
      if (x[e].indexOf("four") > -1)
        console.log("found Four");
    }
```